# How to find gps data and store it in a variable in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make it so that

1. the device asks the user to enable location
2. reads location data
3. stores said data in a variable

I have tried the unity base code and some examples but none of them will output to a static varible
(btw I am very new at unity)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in `LocationService.Start`. ([See here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LocationService.html))

For example (from the official documentation):

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    // First, check if user has location service enabled
    if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
        yield break;

    // Start service before querying location
    Input.location.Start();

    // Wait until service initializes
    int maxWait = 20;
    while (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        maxWait--;
    }

    // Service didn't initialize in 20 seconds
    if (maxWait < 1)
    {
        print("Timed out");
        yield break;
    }

    // Connection has failed
    if (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed)
    {
        print("Unable to determine device location");
        yield break;
    }
    else
    {
        // Access granted and location value could be retrieved
        print("Location: " + Input.location.lastData.latitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.longitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.altitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.horizontalAccuracy + " " + Input.location.lastData.timestamp);
    }

    // Stop service if there is no need to query location updates continuously
    Input.location.Stop();
}
```

Comment: so with this I could set a static varible equal to Input.location.lastData.latitude?

Comment: Yes you can set.